# Inner Products on a real two dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let V be a real two-dimensional vector space with basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$. Find all the
inner products $\langle$–,–$\rangle$ on V which satisfy $\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle = \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle = 1$

I'm able to mess around with a lot of the properties of this, but I really can't figure out how at all to get the required result.

Comment: How many positive-definite symmetric matrices of size $2$ do you know ?

Comment: None! I haven't yet covered positive-definite symmetric matrices. I only have currently a very basic knowledge of inner products.

Comment: Then have look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). You need positive-definite and symmetric for inner products.

Answer (score 1):

The general form of an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by
$$
\langle x,y\rangle = y^tAx,
$$
where $A$ denotes a real positive-definite, symmetric matrix of size $n$. For $n=2$ we can apply Hurwitz criterion, i.e., we obtain the matrices
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a>0$ and $ac-b^2>0$.

Edit: The question has the additional requirement that the inner product is normalised.
This means $1=\langle e_1,e_1\rangle =e_1^tAe_1=a$, and $1=\langle e_2,e_2\rangle =e_2^tAe_2=c$.

Comment: You need to add the condition 
$$\langle e_1,e_1\rangle=\langle e_2,e_2\rangle=1$$

Comment: First, we're not in $\mathbb{R}^2$, just a 2 dimensional vector space. And that doesn't use the condition required!

Comment: @Bobbington: You wrote that $V$ is "a real two-dimensional vector space". That is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.